# Do different thing for first element inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, ecmascript-6

There is a map function like this:

```
{myData.map(item => (
    <Cell
      key={myData.indexOf(item)}
      label={item.label}
      value={item.value}
      email
    />
  ))}
```

Cell is a another component which, if `email` is there, it does something different for that data.

In my case, I want that `email` is available for all elements in `myData` but without the first one. `email` is a **boolean** which is used later by Cell component.

So I've tried to add the index an use it

```
{myData.map((item, index) => (
    <Cell
      key={myData.indexOf(item)}
      label={item.label}
      value={item.value}
      email={index !== 0 ? email : null}
    />
  ))}
```

Unfortunately, did not work, it says that email is not defined. Is there a way to solve this problem here? I want to solve it inside map function.

Comment: first you could replace `myData.indexOf(item)` for index

Comment: Well, what's `email` supposed to be?

Comment: What is `email` here?

Comment: Should it be `item.email` here: `index !== 0 ? email : null`?

Comment: email is a boolean. if that exists, the fond is different (underlined and blue color)

Comment: if email is let as in the first cod snippet where is no index, it is taken as true for all iterations inside map

Comment: Where is `email` defined?

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: I added the Cell component so it is clear where email is used. It's difficult to make a demo for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing email prop inside `Cell` is boolean. Therefor the existence of it evaluates to true or false.

If that's the case, change to:

```
{myData.map((item, index) => (
    <Cell
      key={myData.indexOf(item)}
      label={item.label}
      value={item.value}
      email={index !== 0}
    />
  ))}
```

EDIT: `index !== 0 ? true : false` -> `index !== 0` brain fart

Comment: Or just `email={index !== 0}`

Comment: I guess that eslint doesn't let me use boolean values there but I changed it to ` email={index !== 0 ? 1 : 0}` and it works